# When I commit to a Forked Repo will that affect in any way the Repo from which I forked from?

Tags: git, open-source, github

This is a Question regarding the topic of: *Contributing to Open Source*. Given that this could be daunting for a newbie. I thought it's best to just ask.

So the process goes Like this:

1. Fork Repo
2. Clone Repo to Local Machine
3. Set up remote upstream
4. Create branch to work on new features
5. Work on new features
6. Commit changes to branch
7. Fetch upstream
8. Update local master ($ git checkout master; git pull upstream master)
9. Rebase issue branch
10. Push branch to GitHub
11. Issue pull request

I'm concerned about step 9. Will this step affect the Original Repo **from which I Forked from?**(will my commits to my fork be seen by the owner?) Or do I have all the liberties I want with my own Fork? As long as I don't Issue a Pull request that is (I'm a little confused because they advice not to work on the master branch ever)

Additional Question: Following the same logic (and assuming my commits won't affect the original repo) Can I send the branch(es) I create locally for new features to my own fork? something like:

```
git push origin new-branch
```

*Will this command send the branch to my own fork only?*

I know these questions are obviously totally novice material, But more than ever I need to know how do it right, I appreciate all your comments and suggestions.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"When I commit to a Forked Repo will that affect in any way the Repo from which I forked from?"

**No.  It's not an issue unless they explicitly pull from your fork.**

"Will this command send the branch to my own fork only?"

**Yes.**

Comment: Could you possibly elaborate a little more on the specific Questions I just asked? I know it's a pain, but It'll help me a lot. Thank you very much nonetheless

Comment: What I see right now is exactly what I would also have typed.

Comment: Thank you! Still a little incomplete, (well, compared to the fully detailed answers that are usually given here). But still useful in the sense that it makes my confidence about contributing build up.

Comment: @user766388, you still haven't told me what is incomplete.  I answered the main question, but if there's a detail you're not clear on, let me know.

Comment: Can you help me with your answer to this one: will my commits to my own fork be seen by the owner?

Comment: @user766388, only in the sense that they can see your repo in GitHub, or choose to pull from it (both if it's public).

Comment: Matthew, one last Question: Is it important that my fork as seen on GitHub reflects or displays the latest changes? it is currently out of date, and reflects what was done (commited) like 2 weeks ago.

Comment: @user766388, it will show anything you've pushed to GitHub.  However, it's up to you if and when to push.

Answer (score 3):

Your fork of a repo is your own little repo that you can do whatever you want with. The owner of the original repo ( and others ) will see that you have forked the repo, but apart from that, will not be affected by your day-to-day activities on that repo. Only when you give a pull request will the owner of the original repo get some notification of what you have done etc.

So this means that you are free to rebase ( of course assuming that no one else is using your forked repo e.g your teammates etc. ), push and even delete the fork.

Comment: Cool, This is the type of answer I was looking for! So, the only time in which code from my own fork will affect the one from the original is when the owner of the original decides to merge my branch after reviewing a Pull Request?

Comment: @user766388 - Yes, and that is why it is a PULL request and not a PUSH.

Comment: @manojlds do we need to explicitly change the remote url to my fork?